# Whatsapp integration directly with contacts

Tags: 8.0, people-hub, whatsapp

I have a HTC 8S with Windows Phone 8 Whatsapp installed.

When I go to the People hub and click a contact, I don't have the option to send a Whatsapp message directly from there, I only have phone, sms and e-mail options. So I first have to open Whatsapp in order for me to send a message to that person. This is particularly annoying when I’ve pinned certain persons to my homescreen for quick access.
So the lack of this feature costs me time. Is there a way to have the Whatsapp contact options made available with a contact?

I've also contacted Whatsapp with this question, but perhaps there's something more to this issue, such as Microsoft not allowing this via their API?

Answer (score 4):

What you're referring to is a restricted partner API. And I don't think it's currently available to WhatsApp.

You could request that WhatsApp implement contact tiles, so you can pin contact tiles that open directly in WhatsApp.

*(Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft)*

Comment: Surely Whatsapp is mainstream enough now to be included into the People Hub. Facebook is, and Whatsapp is owned by facebook now.